# Sorting background colors in a range of cells using custom comparator function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I use a script to sort a sheet on a particular item in a column.
Data in this column is a number preceded by letters so the normal `sort` method from the `range` or `sheet` class does not work properly.

Here is the script, the actual question comes below.

```
function sortIDs(){ // test on column 5
  sortOnNumbersInCol(5);
}

function sortOnNumbersInCol(col){ // numeric sort except for 2 first rows on numeric value in column col
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('copie de travail');
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  //Logger.log('length départ='+data.length);
  var codes = data.shift();
  var headers = data.shift();
  var dataOut=[];
  for(var n=0 ; n<data.length ; n++){
    if(data[n][col] != ''){
      dataOut.push(data[n]);
      //Logger.log('data['+n+']['+col+']='+data[n][col].substring(7)+'|');
    }
  }  
  dataOut.sort(function(a,b){
    var aE,bE;
    aE=a[col].substring(7); // the numeric part comes at the 7 th position (and following)
    bE=b[col].substring(7);
    return aE - bE
  })
  dataOut.unshift(headers);
  dataOut.unshift(codes);
  sh.getRange(1,1,dataOut.length,dataOut[0].length).setValues(dataOut);
}
```

This works perfectly for data sorting but it doesn't care about cell colors obviously...
Some of my coworkers use colors to designate items in this sheet and when I sort the range the colors don't follow.

So my question is : How can I sort this sheet with my specific criteria and keep the correlation with cell colors ?

below is a screen capture of sheet data

[image: screenshot of the sheet]

If I run my script on this range the colors won't move... that's my problem ;)

Comment: Well, you can pair [`getBackgrounds`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackgrounds) with [`setBackgrounds`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setBackgrounds(String)), just extend the comparator  to swipe the colors in the matrix of background colours, I think that should do the trick nicely. After all, `setValues` does not care about colours or any formatting for that matter

Comment: That was my idea too but I can't figure out how to pair the sorting process... any practical solution ?

Comment: and thanks for the title edit by the way, I had no inspiration, yours is very nice !

Comment: Hm, you can prepare a `getBackgrounds` array, then instead of pushing values in `dataOut` array, how about expanding a little and pushing an object for each value with properties like `{ color : "000000", value: "" }`. Or what TheMaster said below for an optimal solution:

Comment: Create a map of  {data:colors}. Then you could easily map the sorted data to colors

Comment: @Sergeinsas - re:edit - thank you, too bad I am editing more than answering as of late :) Anyways, since TheMaster is already adding an answer, I will leave that to them,  I like the idea about mapping values to colors more than creating an extra matrix of data structures that came to my mind from the start

Comment: FWIW, The normal sort method can be used if you use proper numbering like `01` instead of `1`: `MCINPRO04` instead of `MCINPRO4`. Constant 2 or 3 digits should work.

Comment: @TheMaster, good to know :) but the whole system coupled with a webapp that generates private access urls is online for a couple of months... too late to change the ID structure (this id is part of the identifier)

Comment: @Sergeinsas - maybe introduce a mapper that will map old ID structure to new upon generating them - that will save you some trouble?

Comment: @OlegValter this color keeping issue was really a very special case for a particular group of users, otherwise colors are not significant (and not modified). The whole project is very stable in its present form, I don't feel like risking any problem ;)  btw, I need to learn the use of map and the new V8 syntax but I'm short on free time these days...

Comment: @Sergeinsas - well, if it is more trouble than its worth - sure :) Although new `Map` built-in is useful, you can do away with a good old object acting as map + dynamic properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**:

Another way to do this without the space complexity is by sorting the keys/indexes instead of the actual array.

```
function sortOnNumbersInCol(col = 5) {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('copie de travail');
  const dataRg = sh.getDataRange();
  const noOfHeadrs = 2;
  const rg = dataRg.offset(
    //Remove  headers before getting values
    noOfHeadrs,
    0,
    dataRg.getNumRows() - noOfHeadrs,
    dataRg.getNumColumns()
  );
  let data = rg.getValues();
  let colors = rg.getBackgrounds();

  /* Filter Empty rows if needed 
  [data, colors] = [data, colors].map(arr =>
    arr.filter((_, i) => data[i][col] !== '')
  );*/

  const dataKeys = [...data.keys()];
  dataKeys.sort(function(a, b) {
    return data[a][col].substring(7) - data[b][col].substring(7);
  });
  const [dataOut, colorsOut] = [data, colors].map(arr =>
    dataKeys.map(i => arr[i])
  );
  const outRg = sh.getRange(
    noOfHeadrs + 1,
    1,
    dataOut.length,
    dataOut[0].length
  );
  outRg.setValues(dataOut);
  outRg.setBackgrounds(colorsOut);
}
```

---

Create a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of {data:colors}:

```
  const rg = sh.getDataRange();
  const data = rg.getValues();
  const colors = rg.getBackgrounds();
  const dcMap = data.reduce((mp, row, i) => mp.set(row[col], colors[i]),new Map)
```

Then after sorting, you could use the sorted values as key and create a new sorted color array:

```
  dataOut.sort(function(a,b){
    var aE,bE;
    aE=a[col].substring(7); // the numeric part comes at the 7 th position (and following)
    bE=b[col].substring(7);
    return aE - bE
  })
  dataOut.unshift(headers);
  dataOut.unshift(codes);

  const sortedColors = dataOut.map(row=>dcMap.get(row[col]));
  const outRg = sh.getRange(1,1,dataOut.length,dataOut[0].length);
  outRg.setValues(dataOut);
  outRg.setBackgrounds(sortedColors);
}
```

Comment: I accepted your answer since it seems like a good one but unfortunately it's a bit above my javascript level ;) I'm stupidly stuck on a syntax error on this   `const dcMap = data.reduce((mp, row, i) => mp.set(row[col], colors[i]),new Map)` or if I want to use your first option how do I build dataOutKeys ?

Comment: @Sergeinsas What does the error say? Could you quote the error? Have you enabled v8? To build dataKeys, this is all that is needed: `const dataOutKeys = [...dataOut.keys()];` it is just ``[1,2,3...]``

Comment: ok, I didn't enable V8, I'm attached to my old environment ;)  now it is working, thanks a lot, I'll need to return to the learning process I'm afraid ...

Comment: Thank you for the complete update, this is very clean. I guess that `col=5` in the function parameter is a way to set a default value when no parameter is used ? This V8 version is amazing :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `sort` method from [Class Filter](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter) as this besides including the cells background color  will include other cell properties like notes, comments, data-validation and conditional formatting.

As the OP already mentioned this method can't be used directly as the column to be sorted has composed values (string + consecutive numbers without leading zeros). In order to do this we will need to add an auxiliary column which in this case is relatively easy as the range to be sorted is got by using `getDataRange()`.

NOTES:

The following code use an arrow function so it requires to use the new runtime.

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  // Add the auxiliary column
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var codes = sheet.getRange(1,2,lastRow).getValues();
  var newCodes = codes.map(([value]) => [value.match(/\d{1,}/)]);
  var newColumn = sheet.getRange(1,sheet.getLastColumn()+1,lastRow).setValues(newCodes);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  // Sort
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var filter = range.createFilter();
  filter.sort(values[0].length, true);

  // Remove the filter and the auxiliary column
  filter.remove()
  sheet.deleteColumn(values[0].length)

}
```

Demostration

Before
[image: Before]

After
[image: After]

---

If for any reason you decide to use the old runtime, replace

```
var newCodes = codes.map(([value]) => [value.match(/\d{1,}/)]);
```

by

```
var newCodes = codes.map(function([value]){ return [value.match(/\d{1,}/)]});
```

Comment: The issue was about using a custom filter function, see details in question. I'm afraid this wont be useable in my case

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep things ES5, simply use an object as a map and sort colors and values independently of each other.

```js
/**
 * 
 * @param {(string|number)[]} data
 * @param {string[]} colors
 * @returns {(string|number)[][][]}
 */
function sortOnNumbersInCol(data, colors, col) {

  //var codes = data.shift();
  //var headers = data.shift();

  var map = {};

  for (var n = 0; n < data.length; n++) {
    if (data[n][col] != '') {
      map[colors[n][col]] = data[n][col];
    }
  }

  var dataOut = data.sort(function(a, b) {
    var aE = a[col].substring(7);
    var bE = b[col].substring(7);
    return aE - bE;
  });

  var colorsOut = colors.sort(function(a, b) {
    var aC = map[a[col]].substring(7);
    var bC = map[b[col]].substring(7);
    return aC - bC;
  });

  //dataOut.unshift(headers);
  //dataOut.unshift(codes);
  
  return [
    dataOut,
    colorsOut
  ];
}

//testing is done with ES6 syntax

const createGrid = (parentTable, valGrid, colorGrid) => {
  const {
    firstElementChild
  } = parentTable;
  
  valGrid.forEach((r,rowIdx) => {
    const row = document.createElement("tr");
    
    r.forEach((c,cellIdx) => {
      const cell = document.createElement("td");
      cell.textContent = c;
      cell.style.backgroundColor = colorGrid[rowIdx][cellIdx];
      firstElementChild.append(cell);
    });
    
    firstElementChild.append(row);
  });
};

var col = 2;

var values = [
  [5, 6, "MCINPRO13"],
  [1, 2, "MCINPRO2"],
  [7, 8, "MCINPRO24"],
  [3, 4, "MCINPRO9"]
];

var colors = [
  [0, 0, "#D8D9DA"],
  [0, 0, "#007030"],
  [0, 0, "#6D99B4"],
  [0, 0, "#FF6347"]
];

const before = document.querySelector("#before");
createGrid(before, values, colors);

sortOnNumbersInCol(values, colors, col);

const after = document.querySelector("#after");
createGrid(after, values, colors);
```

```html
<table id="before">
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>

<hr>

<table id="after">
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

1. Note that the snippet below has header `shift` > `unshift` flow
   disabled for ease of testing and `setValues` removed to make the
   snippet runnable.
2. For simplicity of the snippet, `sort` is also performed directly on the `data` array, so you will have to map over the initial data to keep things pure: `data = data.map(function (v) { return v; })`.